# How to store media files on other location before it gets deleted on publishing in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In Media library I have created one node called **Product pdfs** and under this item I have uploaded one pdf and now one child item **Child pdf 1** is created under **Product pdfs** node which contains the pdf file.

Now I delete **Child pdf 1** node and if I publish **Product pdfs** node pdf file will also deleted.
But I want to store Child pdf file somewhere other location before it gets deleted while publishing Product pdfs node.
How can I achieve this.

Can we achieve this by using EventQueue 
OR
We have to make changes in pipeline processor.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you move the item to an archived folder or just [archive it](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/managing_items/archive_and_restore_an_item?sc_lang=en)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to store / copy your media **before** item is deleted, you may need to implement an event handler. Event you are looking is called **item:deleting** (not to confuse with item:deleted). So, in your configuration register your event handler:

```
<event name="item:deleting">
  <handler type="Your.Assembly.Name.And.Handler.Class, Your.Assembly.Name" method="OnItemDeleting" />
  ... other event handlers ...   
</event>
```

Implement **OnItemDeleting** method within that class, something like below:

```
 protected void OnItemDeleting(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
      if (args == null)
          return;

    Item obj = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
     Assert.IsNotNull((object) obj, "No item in parameters");

    // do some actions to manipulate your media here, before it is deleted
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Martin for quick reply.
So to do that we have to implement event handler NOT event queue or pipeline.

Comment: It all depends on your architecture, if that happens on a standalone CD server, or not. You need to be very clear on architecture, how and where do you store your media items and how they are synchronized. If you want to sync changes done on one of your CDs with CM and from there to re-publish to the rest of CDs - please read my blog article on how to do that with EventQueue. But in ANY case you will need to implement event handlers (locally to specific server) like I wrote above.  http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/editing-content-on-a-cd-server-part-2-event-queue-to-sync-data-with-master